# Cannot persist validation result to display in a view

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a form which suppose to diplay errors in case of unsuccessful validation by Spring. I think I have ModelMap passed back to `dslr` view but for some reason no errors are being displayed. How to fix it?

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/s", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showHTMLResponsePOST(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("dslrForm") DSLR dslrForm,
                                       BindingResult result,
                                       ModelMap model){
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
            DSLRDAO planedao = new DSLRDAO();
            planedao.update(dslrForm);
            return "redirect:s?id="+dslrForm.getDslrId();
        }
        else {
            return "dslr";
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>DSLRs</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="/resources/js/dslr.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="s">servlet</a> |
<a href="">log.txt</a>
<br>
<form:form action="s?action=save" method="POST" comandName="dslr">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />

    <input type="hidden" name="dslrId" value="${dslrForm.dslrId}"/>
    <c:if test="${errors.size() > 0}">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">Can't save, input contains errors!</div>
    </c:if>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>id:</td>
            <td>${dslrForm.dslrId}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>model:</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${dslrForm.model}" name="model"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="model" cssClass="error" ></form:errors></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>price:</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${dslrForm.price}" name="price"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="price" cssClass="error" ></form:errors>  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>description:</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${dslrForm.description}" name="description"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="description" cssClass="error" ></form:errors>   </td>
        </tr></table>
    <input type="submit" value="save">

</form:form>
```

Comment: Try changing to `commandName="dslrForm"` in the form tag and let me know

Comment: Thanks! It works. One mode thing I have constraints defined like this  `@Range(min=0,max=99999,message = "price cannot be bigger than 99999")` but the error I receive in the view is different `Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property price; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "o"`. How to get my own error message I defined?

Comment: I will add my previous comment as an answer

Comment: I will also add a comment in that answer for custom messages

Comment: It seems however that you are not sending an int for the field annotated with `@Range` and that is why the validation does have your message. You should post that as a different question if you can't find it, because it will be confusing for future readers to have two totally different problems in the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to made some minor modifications in your view to get it to work correctly with Spring MVC. Change to form line to:

`<form:form action="s?action=save" method="POST" commandName="dslrForm">`

In case you want to have custom messages, you can follow the instructions of [this](http://www.silverbaytech.com/2013/04/16/custom-messages-in-spring-validation/) post or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900329/2504224) SO answer